# I am not able to install package using my hosted repository

Tags: repository, redhat, rpm

```
yum -d0 -e0 -y --disablerepo\=\* --enablerepo\=my-repo-name install ksh-20120801-34.el7
```

gives:

```
Delta RPMs disabled because /usr/bin/applydeltarpm not installed.
Error downloading packages:
  ksh-20120801-34.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

though "ksh-20120801-34.el7" is available in the repo I am getting the above error.

I have tried cleaning up, disabling and enabling of repo but still no luck . Any help on this could be much appreciated.

Comment: to avoid typing version number errors, did you try `yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=my-reponame install ksh` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for trying to help me out here. In my case solution was simple and debug goes like below.

1. Was trying to **wget** the package from the repo. Though connection was successful i was not able to download the package.
   2 . My team-mate analysed the mounts in the repo and we got to know that they were not mounted properly so he remounted filesystems and post that i was able to download and it solved the install step as well.

Answer (score 2):

One step to debug it would be to list the repo and see what is on the list:

```
# yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=my-repo-name list | grep ksh
```

You can also try without `20120801-34.el7` suffix. So the command would be the following:

```
yum -d0 -e0 -y --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=my-repo-name install ksh
```

```
[root@ms-node0101 ~]# yum install -y ksh.el7
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
No package ksh.el7 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

```
[root@ms-node0101 ~]# yum install ksh-20120801-139
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
No package ksh-20120801-139 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

```
[root@ms-node0101 ~]# yum install -y ksh
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ksh.x86_64 0:20120801-139.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                            Arch                                                  Version                                                            Repository                                                 Size
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 ksh                                                x86_64                                                20120801-139.el7                                                   Local-Base                                                885 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 885 k
Installed size: 3.1 M
Downloading packages:
ksh-20120801-139.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                                       | 885 kB  00:00:01
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : ksh-20120801-139.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                               1/1
  Verifying  : ksh-20120801-139.el7.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                               1/1

Installed:
  ksh.x86_64 0:20120801-139.el7

Complete!
```

Comment: nice try helping him out, but I think your answer won't solve his problem. The command `yum install ksh-20120801-139.el7` would probably have worked on your system. You can try that out.
The `.el7` is part of the release number, you cannot cut the release number in two, that will never work.

Comment: Eh, I see. Indeed `ksh-20120801-139.el7` works fine. I was confused by -139 in my case. `ksh-20120801` and `ksh-20120801-139.el7` work fine. But `ksh-20120801-139` does not work.

Comment: anyways you're helping him on the way. You have my upvote :) Keep up the good work!